# Global event handler for TextBox getting focus by mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a situation when I want to detect when a TextBox, anywhere in the application, has been brought into focus by the user clicking on it with the mouse, or touch. I have "solved" this by adding a global event handler like this:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(txt_MouseLeftButtonUp), true);
```

...

```
void txt_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.OriginalSource is TextBox)
  {
    // Do somthing
  }
}
```

However, if the user clicks the edges of a textbox instead of in the middle, quite often an hosting control (Grid, Border etc.) receives the mouse event and somehow passes this on to the contained TextBox, that will handle it and receive focus. This makes the approach above fruitless as the TextBox will not be the e.OriginalSource in this case and I have found no way of identifying that a TextBox was brought into focus by click.

Deriving TextBox and overriding OnMouseDown for instance, will catch this event and I guess this path could be explored to find a solution to the problem but that would require me to use a custom TextBox everywhere.

Anyone out there with a nice solution for this?

This is an example that will trigger the problem. By clicking the edges of the TextBoxes, the grid will handle the mouse event and focus will be passed on to the TextBox.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Background="Red">
      <TextBox>2323</TextBox>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Margin="200,0,0,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Background="Red" Focusable="False">
      <TextBox>2323</TextBox>
    </Grid>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: What if the TextBox received focus without clicking (e.g. by using the Tab key), do you want to detect that too?

Comment: Good point, only by mouse clicks. Tab key focus should be ignored.

Comment: Please explain what you want to use this for so it will be easier to provide suggestions.

Comment: I want to bring up a touch keyboard every time a TextBox is clicked in the application. And only when its clicked by mouse or touch.

Comment: Why do you want to exclude the Tab key causing the focus?

Answer (score 1):

The `GotMouseCapture` event seems to work:

```
AddHandler(UIElement.GotMouseCaptureEvent,
    new MouseEventHandler(OnGotMouseCapture), true);

...

void OnGotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is TextBox)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I click on **TextBox** elements with the mouse this event handler is fired, however focus changes made via keyboard do not fire the event.

Comment: I'm afraid this will not catch the focus action triggered by clicking in the outer edges of the TextBox (so far out that in fact the hosting control receives the mouse event and somehow pass that on to the TextBox).

Comment: @Kente It's not the "hosting" control receiving the click event and passing it on, it _is_ actually the **TextBox** control. You can see this by attaching event handlers for the **MouseEnter** and **MouseLeave** events. There does seem to be a strange issue with the **TextBox** control, in that (in some layout scenarios) the mouse capture area seems to extend one-pixel to the right of the control's bounds. I can only assume this is because WPF's layout system is not based on whole-pixels and there is some layout rounding going on.

Comment: @Kente Also, the default **TextBox** control template consists of a **Border** element with a **ScrollViewer** inside it. Only the **ScrollViewer** will perform the mouse capture and raise the **GotMouseCapture** event. As there is margin/padding between the **ScrollViewer** and the containing **Border** element, clicking on this gap will give the **TextBox** focus but _will not_ raise the mouse capture event. I can't think of any way to resolve this (you can't add padding to the **ScrollViewer** as it is ignored; you could however remove it from the **Border**).

Comment: @Kente Strictly speaking it's not always a **Border** element inside the control template, however it is always _some kind of decorator_ that has a **ScrollViewer** inside it. The **ScrollViewer** is named `PART_ContentHost`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply handle the `GotFocus` event for each TextBox.

Comment: That will trigger TextBoxes brought into focus by the Tab key as well. This will not work for me.